# Hi, I'm building a swagger 2.0 API in Stoplight. I am having trouble referencing a model that is defined in 'definitions' and exists a model

Tags: api, stoplight

The referenced data model (Body Parameters) is not visible in the UI html. I tried it in Swagger Hub with the same negative results.

Here is the troublesome segment from the API yaml:

```
parameters
  -in: body
   schema:
     $ref: '#/definitions/TransactionDetails
   name: Transaction Details
   description: Body Parameters
   required: true
```

No errors or issues are reported in Stoplight or Swagger Hub.

Any help much appreciated!

The referenced data model (Body Parameters) is not visible in the UI html. I tried it in Swagger Hub with the same negative results.

I am expecting the Body section in the UI to be populated with parameters from the model file /definitions/TransactionDetails. It remains empty. It is almost as if the model is not active or available.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

The swagger 2 file must contain the following:

consumes:

- application/json
  produces:
- application/json